# Exception in thread "Thread-340" Android + Realm

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

I have been seeing this error everytime I compile my project. I am currently using Realm but the older version.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-340" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.security.MessageDigest.update(MessageDigest.java:323)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.digest(MessageDigest.java:398)
    at io.realm.processor.Utils.sha256Hash(Utils.java:153)
    at io.realm.processor.RealmAnalytics.getAnonymousUserId(RealmAnalytics.java:155)
    at io.realm.processor.RealmAnalytics.generateJson(RealmAnalytics.java:129)
    at io.realm.processor.RealmAnalytics.getUrl(RealmAnalytics.java:125)
    at io.realm.processor.RealmAnalytics.send(RealmAnalytics.java:95)
    at io.realm.processor.RealmAnalytics.access$000(RealmAnalytics.java:55)
    at io.realm.processor.RealmAnalytics$1.run(RealmAnalytics.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Note: Version 0.88.3 of Realm is now available: http://static.realm.io/downloads/java/latest
Note: Processing class ProjectTaskDB
Note: Processing class ProjectTaskDBList
Note: Creating DefaultRealmModule
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: Are you using encryption? If yes, can you confirm that the key is not `null`?

Comment: @razzledazzle no I am not using any encryption at all.

Comment: Right, it's a compile time issue. Are you using the Realm plugin? Would be nice to know more in detail on how you've set Realm up.

Comment: Better try using the most recent version, related bugs have been resolved.
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1336 Not sure about the current status though.

Comment: See `Utils.java`, line `153`.

Comment: @xdevs23 that's not my class though.

Comment: @razzledazzle ok I will send more of my setup and put it here! Thanks!

Comment: @xdevs23 it's internal to Realm compilation, all that can be done is to update

Answer (score 1):

The bug that you are experiencing is reported to have been [resolved](http://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1336). You can try upgrading Realm to the most recent version.

This [article](https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/) might be relevant to you.

Comment: Got it! Will check it later! Thanks!